# How To Create Getter Setter In Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, getter-setter

I'm using Angular 7. I want to get and set variable in typescript

## My Code login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  public username:string;
  public token:string;
  public fullname:string;
  constructor() { }
  set setUser(val: string){
    this.username = val;
  }
  set setToken(val:string){
    this.token=val;
  }
  set setFullName(val:string){
    this.fullname=val;
  }
  get getUser():string{
    return this.username;
  }
  get getToken():string{
    return this.token;
  }
  get getFullName():string{
    return this.fullname;
  }
}
```

## And My Code In Login.Component.ts

```
fLogin(user, pass) {
    this.users.setUser=user;
}
```

## And My Code In Customer.Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import {LoginService} from "../login.service"
import { NgLocalization } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers',
  templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers.component.css']
})
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public user:LoginService) {

  }
  loadData() {
    console.log(this.user.getUser)
  }
    ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }
}
```

> I expect Set Value In **Login.Component.ts** And Get Value in **Customer.Component.ts**
>
> How to it working or the other it working?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1) Ensure your login.component.ts file also injects the service.

```
constructor(public user:LoginService)
```

2) Ensure that no module or component has a `providers` array containing your service.

If you register the service using the `providedIn: 'root'` as you have, and *don't* register the service again in any `providers` array, then the service should be a singleton and work as you expect.

Also, the naming of your getters and setters is incorrect. The getter and setter should have the *same* name, as they are just another way to define a property:

```
  get user():string{
    return this.username;
  }
  set user(val: string){
    this.username = val;
  }
  get token():string{
    return this.token;
  }
  set token(val:string){
    this.token=val;
  }
  get fullName():string{
    return this.fullname;
  }
  set fullName(val:string){
    this.fullname=val;
  }
```

You then access those getter/setter properties just like any other declared properties.

```
 this.fullName = "Joe Smith"; // to set the value and call the setter

 console.log(this.fullName); // to reference the value.
```

**In your customer component:**

```
  constructor(public loginService:LoginService) {

  }
  loadData() {
    console.log(this.loginService.user)
  }
```

NOTE: I renamed your constructor parameter to better identify it.

**In your login component:**

```
  constructor(public loginService:LoginService) {

  }

  fLogin(user, pass) {
     this.loginService.user = user;
  }
```

Comment: Which part is returning undefined? Consider adding an update to your original question that shows your updated code and current issue.

Comment: Thank you for your angular fundamental course at Plural sight.

Answer (score 1):

you need only have 2 same functions, one with prefix set and another else with prefix get:

```
****in the Service User

private name: string;

public get info() {
  return name;
}

public set info(val) {
  this.name = val;
}


************ usage in other components or services
this.User.info = 'your name'; // for set

const yourName = this.User.info; // for get
```