# How to show only unique values from data instead of all

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I wanted to show only unique values in the div instead of all.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of allUser">
{{user.gender}}
</div>
```

But right now, it's populating all the values as per the screenshot

[image]

What changes do I need to do to show only unique values here?
*It should show 2 values as : Male and Female.*

Comment: You could use set that will remove your duplication

Comment: here's a good example on how you can filter your values to get only the unique ones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: @yazan will that be a filter something like `{{user.gender | unique }}`

Comment: Please don't post relevant code/input/output as images. A good resource is [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a getter in ts file(name could be anything).

```
get uniqueGenders(){
    return new Set(this.allUser.map(x=>x.gender))
}
```

and use it in template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of uniqueGenders">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

read more about getter and setter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682011/how-to-create-getter-setter-in-angular)

Comment: it's throwing an error saying `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: how are you getting `allUser` data? Please share code

Comment: or put a check `get uniqueGenders(){
    return this.allUser? new Set(this.allUser.map(x=>x.gender)): []
}`

Answer (score 0):

I guess they are stored in an array..?
You can use the set (as mentioned by yazan)

let ngFor=['male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female']

let gender = [...new Set(ngFor)]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set